# How do I save the last value of my recursive function in MASM?

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, masm32

Essentially, I wrote a function that finds the GCD of two numbers recursively. I am trying to store the last value of the recursion call into firstVal, so I can print it to the screen. The way I have it written prints the all values of the recursion.

```
GCD proc firstVal: dword, secondVal: dword

mov edx, 0         ;clear edx for div
cmp secondVal, 0   ;if b is 0 (only way to exit recursion)
jz foundGCD        ;then a is the gcd

mov eax, firstVal  ;to find a mod b
div secondVal      ;div a by b and check ah

mov ecx, secondVal       ;old b in ecx
mov firstVal, ecx        ;now store ecx in a
mov secondVal, edx       ;store a mod b in b

invoke GCD, firstVal, secondVal  ;recursion

foundGCD:
call crlf          ;newline

mov eax, firstVal  ;firstVal holds the gcd
call writedec      ;I think the problem sits somewhere here?
call waitmsg

ret
GCD endp
```

How do I save the last value of the recursive proc?

Comment: You don't "save" it per se, you return it so it's in EAX for each return.

Comment: That's my issue. When I move the value into EAX and print it, it prints all values of EAX throughout the recursion. Is it possible to access only the last instance of EAX somehow? I am planning on invoking another PROC after the recursion. If I do that now, it passes all the values into the proc, and it invokes the proc more than once. If that is not possible, how would I return only the last instance value of EAX?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that after the return from your recursive call, execution continues at the statement that follows the `invoke GCD` call: the `foundGCD` label, which will generate output.

What you should do after the `invoke` is handle the result of recursion, which in this case is a simple `ret`.

```
invoke GCD, firstVal, secondVal  ;recursion
ret
```

With that, we can see that the recursion is *tail recursion*, so the recursive call can be replaced with an unconditional jump (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: So at what point would I call to print the gcd(firstVal)? The assignment specifically asks to use recursion so I can't replace it with jmp.

Comment: @KarimKabbara: You call it from a `main` function or something, and print the return value.  You shouldn't print from inside your recursive computation function.

Comment: After some testing, I noticed that my proc's first recursive instance holds the GCD, not the last like I had said previously. Printing the value after the proc executes leaves me with the incorrect number. What is the best method to access the first instance of eax?